# Why is NaN (not a number) only available for doubles?

Tags: c#, types

I have a business class that contains two nullable decimal properties. A third property returns the result of multiplying the other two properties. If HasValue is true for the two nullable types then I multiply and return the result. I have a few options for the return value if one or both of the properties is null:

- Return 0
- Throw an exception
- Return a magic number (-1)
- Return decimal? (EDIT -- see comments)

I thought one of my options would be to return NaN, but I see that this is only possible for the double type. Why is this?

For the record, returning 0 makes the most sense in this case and that's what I plan to do unless someone has a better suggestion.

Comment: Why don't you return a nullable decimal in the third property?

Comment: Indeed - if you go the "decimal?" route, you don't even need to do any checks - the C# compiler provides "lifted" operators for you: "decimal? Calculated {get {return PropA * PropB;}}"

Comment: I was too busy looking at the trees to notice the forest and I missed the obvious solution. I didn't know about "lifted" operators so I'm glad I missed this answer because I learned something new from it.

Comment: ..Nan is available for doubles and floats

Comment: `float.NaN` exists. It's not just for doubles.

Comment: The standard has NaNs for decimals, [see here](http://speleotrove.com/decimal/damodel.html). .NET doesn't care though, not sure why.

Comment: Oftentimes magic numbers are used when you have no admin/design control over the persistence layer (e.g. the database). But they usually introduce troublesome side-effects. I wouldn't use values like `-1` or `0`, because they are also used as normal values. `int.MinValue` or `int.MaxValue` (for `int`) are good candidates for magic numbers - but you have to exclude them from the range of valid values if you're using them. If you can, always favor nullable types (`int?`).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Integral types in .NET use two's complement system for representation. While they could reserve some bit patterns for special values, they chose not to. `double` and `float` use a completely different representation system (IEEE 754) which reserves some special bit patterns for NaN, +Infinity, -Infinity, ...

One reason that NaN and Infinity values make more sense for floating point arithmetic is that operations could result division by zero, not only because the divisor is actually zero, but because it's too small to be represented by the type. As a result, if that wasn't the case, you could have some valid calculation mysteriously throw a divide by zero exception. This won't happen for `int` types as they are exact and don't have a precision error.

`decimal` is designed to be used for "real-world" decimal floating point numbers. It's rarely subject to calculations that `double` and `float` are designed to do. What would `NaN` express for a real world number?

Leaving reasons behind it alone, it is what it is and there's nothing we could do about it, so the best route to go is to use nullable types (they are designed to help with exactly this kind of situation). It's the *right way* to solve this problem. If you don't want to do that (and exceptions don't make sense), you should resort to the magic number solution. If you chose to do so, just make sure it's outside of the domain of valid results.

#### EDIT (very common misconception about decimal):

[As also noted by MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx), `decimal` is not fixed point. It is a floating point number:

> A decimal number is a floating-point value that consists of a sign, a numeric value where each digit in the value ranges from 0 to 9, and a scaling factor that indicates the position of a floating decimal point that separates the integral and fractional parts of the numeric value.

Comment: "What would NaN express for a real world number?" sqrt(-1) ?

Comment: Mark Pim: You really want to use decimal for complex arithmetic? ;)

Comment: Minor correction; 'decimal' is fixed-point not floating point.

Comment: @kervin: No, decimal is a "decimal" floating point type, as opposed to binary floating point. It has got exponent and mantissa so it's floating point.

Comment: @Mehrdad: In complex arithmetic sqrt(-1) = sqrt({-1,0}) = {0,1}. It's only in Real arithmetic that sqrt(-1) may be considered to "not be a number" and thus represented by NaN.

Comment: @Daniel: Good point. That was mostly meant as a joke. That doesn't affect what I meant to say: If an application of a decimal number ever wants to calculate `sqrt(-1)`, that's 99% a fatal error that should cause an exception.

Comment: "What would NaN express for a real world number?" An overflow, just as it does with doubles.

Comment: How about not initialized `int` variables? They do not yet contain a number. And if they are persisted in a database as non-nullable, they are also not (or should not be) `int?`

Comment: A little more info on my comment: I had a situation where a field value in the database is integer and hence the EF mapped int cannot be nullable. But somehow I need to flag that there has been never a value entered into that field - hence `NaN` would be ideal. Of course, if the database is allowed to be changed, one could simply make the field nullable. But if you can't - it gets tricky.

Comment: "What would NaN express for a real world number?" - Average annual sector gains over 0 years. NaN doesn't suddenly become useless because decimals function in the "real world". 

Unlike doubles, which only ever represent the average height of unicorns and distance to pots of gold.

Comment: Another real-world example: I work extensively with CNC machines, which use _decimal_ floating point values (not binary floating point) because humans _really really really_ expect "0.1" to be exactly representable as a physical measurement in a manufacturing machine. If you want to talk to such machines, your best bet is to use _decimal_ unless you want to introduce issues your users will find inexplicable. And there's nothing weird about computing the sqrt of such numbers.