# .NET numeric library supporting decimal and NaN

Tags: c#, .net, porting

I wonder if there is any .NET numeric library which supports decimal and NaN?

I searched in Google, but only found some ones without decimal or NaN support. Do you know any one supporting decimal and NaN?

---

Sorry for not enough information! Actually I want to port some R code into C#. R has NA for missing data in matrix. As I can imagine, one way in C# to handle this situation is to store data with missing ones in Nullable< decimal > temporarily, and remove the NAs and translate Nullable< decimal > into decimal before calculation; another ways is to use a library support Nullable< decimal > or NaN directly, therefore saving the time without copying large data. Is there a better ways?

Comment: What operations exactly are you looking for?  .NET defines a `decimal` type and `NaN` exists in .NET.

Comment: Perhaps you really want a nullable decimal. Whatever, your question is not precise enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean NaN for the decimal type, well, NaN is not a number; in which case you could return a null version of a nullable decimal, as per this:

[Why is Nan (not a number) only available for doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986268/why-is-nan-not-a-number-only-available-for-doubles)

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide an example of where you would need this? .Net supports `decimal` and also `decimal.TryParse()`.

Otherwise I don't think you would need a library for this.