# Why type of NaN is float?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, types

In all languages that I know (python, java, php, javascript etc.) type of NaN is float (double). **Is there any reason for that?** I didn't found such in IEEE 754 [**Note**: IEEE 754-2008 Chapter 6 deals with NaN]. Even if NaN is stored internally as a float, shouldn't it be a separated type (similiar to null  / nil / none)?  **Are there any languages which are using separate type for NaN?**

Comment: Similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986268/why-is-nan-not-a-number-only-available-for-doubles

Comment: IEEE 754 certainly does specify what NaN is (that's where it comes from) ... so your question appears to be based on a flawed premise.

Comment: @GregHewgill : that's why I am asking this question, why rather float than another type? Is that only convenience or traditon?

Comment: @GregHewgill : (It's full version of previous comment) IEEE 754 says: "NaN: Not a number, a symbolic entity encoded in floating-point format"; for me encoded in floating-point format is not equal to having float type (as boolean type which can be encoded with integers 0 and 1) and that's why I am asking this question, why rather float than another type? Is that only convenience or traditon?

Answer (score 3):

Consider floating point division, which I'll refer to as `/`. Pretty obviously, we want it to have the signature

```
function / : float x float -> float
```

But we also want (as per the standard)

```
0 / 0 = NaN
```

So `NaN` needs to be a value of type `float`.

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` has a [specific meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Creation) with regards to floating point numbers. If a language wants to implement "meaningless" results with a value of its own (e.g. `None`, `NA`, `#N/A`, etc.) then it is welcome to, but FP operations require their own specific indicator independent of any language used.