# Any suitable substitute for Double.Nan

Tags: c#

Our group's head has decided to change all Double types to the Decimal inside the application.The reason is not clear but i think it is because of financial stuff. It seems Decimal is more appropriate than Double. Anyway I am going to change it but i don't know how to treat with this statement :

```
cellGridFactory.SetValue(HeightProperty, Double.NaN);
```

The structure of SetValue is

```
SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty,object)
```

I know what Double.NaN means but the problem is there is no Decimal.NaN in C#.
This method comes from an external assemly (dll) so i totally can not analyze it. Do you know any suitable substitute for Double.Nan ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Nan (not a number) only available for doubles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986268/why-is-nan-not-a-number-only-available-for-doubles)

Comment: @Steve No. I have already read that.

Comment: Would you be able to change all `decimal` to `decimal?`, or it's too much of a change in your codebase? You could assign null instead of NaN.

Comment: There is no way we can tell you what a "suitable substitute" is unless you tell us ***why*** you're using not-a-number values in the first place. Are they sentinels? What are considered valid values in your implementation? Etc.

Comment: The conclusion of the linked question is that `Decimal.NaN` is immaterial, that should answer your question.

Comment: Do you think there can be a case you get a NaN using Decimals?

Comment: What type is `HeightProperty` expecting in the first place? Is it `Double` or `Decimal`?

Comment: Searching for "heightproperty NaN" brings up [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.height), which may or may not be related. If this is what the value's going to be used for, it needs to be (or to at some point be converted to) a `Double`.

Comment: So if I had to guess, maybe the correct thing to do would be to leave it as `Double.NaN` because it's supposed to be exactly that value. Don't forget that this is not a financial value. Maybe a group discussion about how GUI sizes should be handled is in order?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're severely misinterpreting your group head's decision. Either that, or your group head is an idiot, but I am guessing the former.

Obviously if an external assembly that you have no source code for and no control over expects to receive `double` values, you cannot change those to `decimal`. Leave them as `double`. `HeightProperty` does not come from your own code, requires `double`, so must not be changed.