# How to fill a multiple array with NaNs in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Have an array 'data', i would like to fill it with NaNs
That’s my approach but it does not work

```
int[,] data = new int[1000, 37];
for (int i = 0, i< sizeof.originaldata, ++i)
{ 
data(i) = NaN
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `int` cant be `NaN`. only `double` and `decimal` and `float` can be NaN.

Comment: [Why is Nan (not a number) only available for doubles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986268/why-is-nan-not-a-number-only-available-for-doubles)

Comment: Sure it won't work - it won't even compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subscript operator is `[]`, not `()`.

You would have to do `data[i, j] = NaN` because it is a multi-dimensional array.

However an `int` cannot be `NaN` anyway, so you can either switch to using `double`, or use an array of `int?` instead and use `null` in place of `NaN`.

Comment: Actually `data` is a 2D array so you need to do something like `data[i,j] = NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` is not of type `int`.  It is of type `double`.  Your assignments will bomb even if you use the c# (`[]`) subscript instead of the VB one (`()`) that you used.

If you must use `int`, you will need to use `int?` for your array and `null` instead of `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your code, first `int`s don't accept `NaN`s, second use `[]` instead of `()` for arrays, third use `;` instead of `,` in the `for` loop, fourth the `NaN` should be used from the `Double` or 'double' class, finally you need a second `for` loop to go through all variables in the 2nd dimension of your array.

See the following updated version that will achieve your intent:

```
Double[,] data = new Double[1000, 37];
for (int i = 0; i <= data.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j <= data.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
    { 
       data[i, j] = Double.NaN;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe using the alias `double` is more widely accepted as a standard

Comment: Thank you! Iam only used to work with MATLAB, i was quite suprised that one line in matlab requires two for loops in c#