# Why does Math.Sign() throws exception when passed a NaN?

Tags: c#, math, nan, sign

Many mathematical functions return NaN when a NaN parameter is passed to them. I was wondering why does Math.Sign() throws an exception when passed a NaN?

How is the decision made for which method return NaN and for which method throw exception. Understanding this will help me to follow the correct design in my own methods.

Comment: Because it is [documented behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ywb0xks3(v=vs.110).aspx): `ArithmeticException` | _value is equal to NaN_.

Comment: @Maxim My question is why this decision has been made? many other Math functions return a NaN when passed a NaN.

Comment: Why should Math.Sign() return `NaN` when the normal behaviour is to return a sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int Math.Sign(Double value)` returns an integer ... (-1/0/1). Double.Nan doesn't seem like an integer.

Probably that's the main reason why it throws an exception.

It could also be discussed why Int.NaN doesn't exist, we already had that discussion at [Why is Nan (not a number) only available for doubles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986268/why-is-nan-not-a-number-only-available-for-doubles)

The behaviour of `Math.Sign(Double)` is documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywb0xks3(v=vs.110).aspx